# Why the subject is written twice in "I wish I found some better sounds"?

Tags: grammar

My question is that, because in the theory of English that I am following it says: wish + present simple is used to express that we want a situation in the present to be different. And the present simple is in this case find, so why is it wrong to say "I wish find"? And does the verb wish belong to a type of group that needs the subject twice?

Answer (score 1):

"I wish I talk" doesn't make any sense.

Are you trying to say "*I wish **to** talk?*" That wouldn't need you to repeat the subject.

Or perhaps you are trying to say "*I wish **I could** talk". That is a perfectly legitimate statement. For example, in the statement "*I think you stink*", 'I' is doing the thinking, and the person they are speaking to is doing the stinking. In "I wish I could talk" the same person is doing the wishing and the prospective talking.

Answer (score 1):

Your text is either wrong or you misunderstood it.

“I wish that he sings

is grammatical and parallel to

> I hope that he sings.

The independent clause is “I wish” or “I hope,” and the dependent clause is “he sings.”

It frequently happens that the word “that” when used to introduce a subordinate clause is omitted, a practice called elision. So it is quite grammatical to say

> I hope he sings.

**However**, as Astralbee has mentioned, it is idiomatic to use modal in the clause subordinate to “wish.”

> I wish that he could sing

> I wish that he would sing

are idiomatic though they mean somewhat different things. Similarly with

> I wish he could sing

> I wish he would sing

Answer (score -1):

The reason for that is you don't always have the same subject in both parts. For example, you could say "I wish he talk", meaning you want someone else to talk. The second "I" in "I wish I speak" simply shows that you want *yourself* to speak.

It would also help to clarify if you used "that", for example "I wish that he talk".

It is relatively uncommon to use the present subjunctive like this in English, however, as we would normally choose a similar alternative, as explained in astralbee's answer.

Comment: *I wish he talk* sounds wrong to me. Maybe *I wish that he talk* or even better *I wish he would talk*.

Comment: It is relatively nonstandard I agree, but it technically makes sense. It's an example of the present subjunctive. A "that" would probably help to clarify, yes.

Comment: This is a terrible answer. “I wish I talk” is simply not grammatical English.

Comment: https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-subjunctive

Comment: @LlamaBoy At that level of formality, “that” would be present. Moreover, it is totally archaic in modern US English.

Comment: Fair enough I suppose

Comment: @JeffMorrow "I wish I talked" would be fine, though.

Comment: @nick012000 True, but that was not the question.